# dev_appserver.py can't find pkg_resources

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

As part of migrating from `ndb` to `cloud-ndb` with GAE Python 2, you need to add the following to `appengine_config.py`:

```
import pkg_resources
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')
pkg_resources.working_set.add_entry('lib')
```

When running locally with `dev_appserver.py`, I get an error that `pkg_resources` can't be found.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you don't need `pkg_resources` when running locally with `dev_appserver.py`.  It is only needed for deployment.

Although I couldn't fix the problem, a good workaround is to update `appengine_config.py` to this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('lib')

try:
    import pkg_resources
    pkg_resources.working_set.add_entry('lib')
except ImportError:
    pass
```

With this modification, it works both locally and when deployed.

Answer (score 0):

> As part of migrating from ndb to cloud-ndb with GAE Python 2, you need to add the following to appengine_config.py:

Was this in the docs somewhere? I'm curious what lead you to that conclusion.

I encountered a weird error with `google-cloud-storage` a while back on both localhost and remote

```
DistributionNotFound: The 'google-cloud-storage' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

It seemed that I had `pkg_resources` in multiple places and that I needed the `pkg_resources` in my `lib` folder to be the one being loaded. I think that the google-cloud-xxxxxxx libs need `pkg_resources` to be in the same directory with them in order for them to work. (printing `pkg_resources.__file__` shows you which pkg_resources is being picked up).

The fix for me was to do `import pkg_resources` & `reload(pkg_resources)` after `vendor.add('lib')`:

```
vendor.add('lib')

import pkg_resources
reload(pkg_resources)
```

I just recently migrated to `google-cloud-ndb` and didnt have to make any further changes in regards to `pkg_resources`, so now I'm thinking that `reload(pkg_resources)` possible saved me from the issue you were facing.